# Drop columns in which a given number of values do not reach threshold

Tags: r

I have a large data set where I would like to remove each column for which less than 10% of the of rows have values are greater than 1. Please assist, thank you!

```
         X0610005C13Rik X0610007N19Rik X0610007P14Rik X0610009B22Rik 
1013      0.9212730       5.098840       59.62392        55.9218       
1014      0.2102610       1.507530       69.87635        48.7867       
1024      0.9948520       1.168450       76.46345        65.7150   
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with sapply.

```
# some example data
set.seed(1)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(200, 0.2, 1.1), ncol=5))

# calculate proportion of data larger than 1
prop_large <- sapply(dat, function(x)length(x[x > 1])/length(x))

# use it to index the dataframe
dat <- dat[,prop_large > 0.1]
```